# FreeMarker not finding the base directory in Ktor

Tags: kotlin, freemarker, ktor

I am pretty new to Kotlin and I am trying to make a ktor exposed server with Freemarker templates to allow me to display data from the database. However, I tried to specify where the templates were, but even after I did, I still get the error of template not found. What am I doing wrong?

```
   val dao = DAOFacadeDatabase(Database.connect("jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", driver = "org.h2.Driver"))
fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
        dao.init()
        install(FreeMarker){
            //allow the connection with the ftl files
            templateLoader = ClassTemplateLoader(this::class.java.classLoader, "templates")
        }

        routing {
            route("/"){
                get{
                    call.respond(FreeMarkerContent("Home.ftl", null))
                }
            }
        }
    }.start(wait=true)
}
```

[Here is the package structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6qqz.png)

Comment: What is your ktor version? Can you please paste the error stack shown in the console?